# [PHP][JSON] Wrong Generate Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have problem which I can't resolve from few days. I need to create array which encode to Json in this format:

```
[
  {
"city": "Wroclaw",
"data": [
  {
    "id": "#",
    "name": "Zlote tarasy",
    "city": "Wroclaw",
    "post_code": "50-545",
    "street": "Ko\u015bciuszki",
    "house_no": "2",
    "flat_no": "4",
    "opening_hours": "8:00 - 16:00",
    "latitude": 52.2330649,
    "longitude": 20.9207689,
    "description": "Opis sklepu"
  },
  {
    "id": "#",
    "name": "Arkadia",
    "city": "Wroclaw",
    "post_code": "50-545",
    "street": "Ko\u015bciuszki",
    "house_no": "2",
    "flat_no": "4",
    "opening_hours": "8:00 - 16:00",
    "latitude": 52.2571437,
    "longitude": 20.9822873,
    "description": "Opis sklepu"
  }
   ]
  }]
```

Here's my generate array method:

```
  public function getCollectionAsArray()
{
    $stores = $this->getStoreCollection();

    $jsonArray = array();

    foreach ($stores as $store) {

        $jsonArray[] = array(
            'city' => $store->getCity(),
            'data' => array(
                [
                    'id'          => $store->getIdentifier(),
                    'name'        => $store->getName(),
                    'post_code'   => $store->getPostCode(),
                    'street'      => $store->getStreet(),
                    'house_no'    => $store->getHouseNo(),
                    'flat_no'     => $store->getFlatNo(),
                    'latitude'    => $store->getLatitude(),
                    'longitude'   => $store->getLongitude(),
                    'description' => $store->getDescription()
                ],
            ),
        );
    }

    return $jsonArray;
}
```

It's working but when I have 2 same citys, it's create new city instead of add data to 'data' array:

```
array (size=4)
 0 =>
array (size=2)
  'city' => string 'Wrocław' (length=8)
  'data' =>
    array (size=1)
      0 =>
        array (size=9)
          ...
 1 =>
array (size=2)
  'city' => string 'Wrocław' (length=8)
  'data' =>
    array (size=1)
      0 =>
        array (size=9)
```

I was trying with array_merge and array_push but not successful. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I think in your foreach loop, if you use an if statement to test if the 'city' value is in the array  `in_array()`,   and if it is to then instruct the code to append the data, and if not instruct the code to add a new city.

Comment: So I guess you are just waiting for someone to do it for you, right?

Comment: No I'm not wainting for answer. I'm trying to doing by myself. I spend much time with this problem and still didn;t resolve it, So I decide to ask people for help (not ready-made solution)

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be

```
public function getCollectionAsArray()
{
    $stores     = $this->getStoreCollection();    
    $jsonArray  = array();  
    $i = 0;     
    foreach ($stores as $store) 
    {    
        $jsonArray[$store->getCity()][] = array( 
                    'id'          => $store->getIdentifier(),
                    'name'        => $store->getName(),
                    'post_code'   => $store->getPostCode(),
                    'street'      => $store->getStreet(),
                    'house_no'    => $store->getHouseNo(),
                    'flat_no'     => $store->getFlatNo(),
                    'latitude'    => $store->getLatitude(),
                    'longitude'   => $store->getLongitude(),
                    'description' => $store->getDescription()
                );
    } 
    $final = array();
    foreach($jsonArray as $key => $json)
    {
        $getkey = myfunction($final,"city",$key);
        if( $getkey )
        {
            $final[$getkey]["data"][] = $json; 
        }
        else
        {
            $final[] = array("city" => $key , "data" => array( 0 => $json ) );
        }
    }
    return $final;
}

function myfunction($products, $field, $value)
{
   foreach($products as $key => $product)
   {
      if ( $product[$field] === $value )
         return $key;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `$i` and just us `[]` for the new array occurance

Comment: It's good answer but still not working, and i think using so many loops is not quite good but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to solve your problem. An idea is just create a PHP array and use `json_encode($your_array_php)`. Like that:

```
$jsonArray = array(
        'city' => $store->getCity(),
        'data' => array(
                'id'          => $store->getIdentifier(),
                'name'        => $store->getName(),
                'post_code'   => $store->getPostCode(),
                'street'      => $store->getStreet(),
                'house_no'    => $store->getHouseNo(),
                'flat_no'     => $store->getFlatNo(),
                'latitude'    => $store->getLatitude(),
                'longitude'   => $store->getLongitude(),
                'description' => $store->getDescription()
        ),
    );
    $jsonArray = json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Comment: Afraid this is not the issue. Read the question again